# Find a gem's root

Tags: ruby

I have 2 gems, `gemA` and `gemB`. I want `gemA` to be installed into B and I want A to be able to manipulate B's filing system.

The first step to this process is finding `gemB` 's root.

In gemA:

```
module GemA
    def self.manipulate_B
         puts __dir__
    end
end
```

In gemB:

```
module GemB
    def self.get_manipulated_by_a
         GemA.manipulate_B
    end
end
```

Upon running `GemB.get_manipulated_by_a` I get this path:

```
/home/jay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/gem_a-0.1.0/lib/gem_a/
```

I get the near root of `gemA`, installed as a gem. Way, way off what I want. I want

```
/home/jay/Documents/Projects/gem_b
```

and of course, if `gemA` was installed in `gemN`

```
/home/jay/Documents/Projects/gem_n
```

**Update**

**I should have said, but GemB is being developed in Documents and GemA is an installed gem to help with the development of GemB. GemB is not installed. I certainly do not want to modify the contents of an installed gem! If you look at my paths you can see what I mean!**

Also, this must be possible because `Rails.root` does it...maybe I'll look at some sauce...

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: 2 reasons for 2 gems. 1 is to rename certain files and certain folders. 2 is to sync some files into another directory for transactional testing purposes.

Comment: It feel to me like a bad idea to manipulate the file structure of another gem. If the other gem is yours, just change it to your needs. If it isn't yours, then do not try to change its internals, you might break it.

Comment: @spickermann totally agree! clarified

Answer (score 3):

In general, you could use the following command to get the installation location of a gem:

```
gem list <gem_name> -d
```

Or, if you're using bundler, then you could also use:

```
bundle show <gem_name>
```

For example, to see the location of `rspec` gem, I do:

```
➜  gem list rspec -d

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rspec (3.2.0)
    Authors: Steven Baker, David Chelimsky, Myron Marston
    Homepage: http://github.com/rspec
    License: MIT
    Installed at: /Users/rislam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1

    rspec-3.2.0
```

Another way to find the location of a gem is to use `Gem::Specification.find_by_name` method like this:

```
2.2.1 :006 > spec = Gem::Specification.find_by_name("rspec")
 => #<Gem::Specification:0x3fd94f85bd04 rspec-3.2.0> 
2.2.1 :007 > spec.gem_dir
 => "/Users/rislam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-3.2.0"
```